# VB.Net Datagridview to Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I wanted to create a datatable based from a 5 column datatable. Also, I would like to remove the last column (it is an image column).

Basically, what I wanted to have is ( a pseudocode )

```
datatable = datagridview.datasource
```

I have tried this, but failed:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = TryCast(dgvCarAccidentInjury.DataSource, DataTable)
```

And this,

```
Dim dt As New DataTable(dgvCarAccidentInjury.DataSource)
```

Again I failed.
I saw this on the c# column but I don't know how to convert it to vb.net, maybe this is the solution but I don't know the syntax in VB.

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(dgvMyMembers.DataSource);
```

I can do it by manually looping but is there an easy way like how it is on C#?

**EDIT**
I have set my datagridview's data manually by doing this line of code,

```
dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows.Add(New String() {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"})
```

Also, there is a 5th column (an image column), actually it is empty. Sorry I have missed this important point out.

**EDIT**

the solution for this problem is this, by manually looping.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim r As DataRow

    dt.Columns.Add("a", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("b", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("c", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("d", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    For i = 0 To dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows.Count - 1
        r = dt.NewRow
        r("a") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
        r("b") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
        r("c") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
        r("d") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
        dt.Rows.Add(r)
    Next
```

Other solutions:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = TryCast(yourdatagridview.DataSource, DataTable)
```

Comment: Can you show us how you set the Datasource?

Comment: I have edited it already.. hmmm

Comment: Yes, and there in lies the problem. You don't have a DataTable to pull out of the DataGridView.

Comment: If You creating datagridview's rows manually. Then maybe more easy Will Be create a datatable manually With same data, assign it to datagridvie.datasource and then use Your datatable as well...

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not the casting:

```
 dt = TryCast(dgvMyMembers.DataSource, DataTable)
```

But your `DataSource` is NOT a `DataTable` but an **array of String**:

```
dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows.Add(New String() {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"})
```

So, make sure that your `DataGridView` was properly connected a `DataTable source` **FIRST**, like:

```
dgvMyMembers.DataSource = dtSourceHere
```

Probably do it your `Form_Load()`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 dgvMyMembers.DataSource = dtSourceHere

End Sub
```

If you want to add your string to your DataGridView, you are better off creating the DataTable add those strings, like:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Names", GetType(String))

    dt.Rows.Add("test1")
    dt.Rows.Add("test2")
    dt.Rows.Add("test3")
    dt.Rows.Add("test4")
```

Then make it as the `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`:

```
    dgvMyMembers.DataSource = dt
```

You could do then later on the `TryCast()` that you desired:

```
    Dim dtNew As New DataTable
    dtNew = TryCast(dgvMyMembers.DataSource, DataTable)
```

Comment: Yes, i did not see it..lol. I tried it in my computer and it works. Probably something else he's missing. Thanks @DonA

Comment: I tried to check that using msgbox(dt.rows.count) but it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Codemunkeee: I think you did not have your DataSource properly set yet and that's why the error. See my updated answer.

Comment: hmmm. I think this has something to do with the datasource? I manually inserted data to the datatable with this
 dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows.Add(New String() {"a", "a", "a", "a"})

Comment: That's not making a dataTable and your DataSource is `Nothing` when you build the structure like that.

Comment: That's right @DonA. So, Codemunkee your code actually works except that your `DataSource` is wrong!

Comment: oh I see, I thought adding data to the datagridview is actually the datasource of that datagridview.. so maybe I'll just have to set it up manually by looping?

Comment: Thanks so much edper and dona, I rated it up. I'll try by manually looping each data on the view and put it on the datatable.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dim DtGrid As DataTable
 DtGrid = CType(dgrd_WWWH.DataSource, DataTable).Copy()
```

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I tried to check the values inside DtGrid using MsgBox(DtGrid.Rows(0).Item(0))

Comment: I think you datasource is empty set break point and then you check

Comment: I am in a similar situation. When trying your suggestions, I get `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try cloning the table? If you set the `DataSource` with a `DataTable` you clone the original. If you have a diff `DataSource` - it will not work converting the `DataSource`.

[DataTable.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim dt As DataTable = originalDt.Clone()
```

Comment: it says "Object variable or With block variable not set."
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = dgvCarAccidentInjury.DataSource.Clone()

Comment: sorry wait ill try again

Answer (score 0):

```
--MENU--
Dim login As New LoginClass
login.ShowDialog()

--CONEXION--
Private conec As SqlConnection
Dim stringCon As String = "Data Source= ;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password="
Public ReadOnly Property prConec() As Object
    Get
        Return conec
    End Get
End Property
Public Sub Conectar()
    Try
        conec = New SqlConnection(stringCon)
        If conec.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            conec.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

--BUSCAR--
funciones.Conectar()
Dim coman As New SqlCommand("sp_cliente", funciones.prConec)
Dim dt As New DataTable
coman.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
coman.Parameters.Add("@i_operacion", SqlDbType.Char, 1, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "B"
dt.Load(coman.ExecuteReader())
grdClientes.DataSource = dt

--INSERTAR--
funciones.Conectar()
Dim coman As New SqlCommand("sp_articulo", funciones.prConec)
coman.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
coman.Parameters.Add("@i_operacion", SqlDbType.Char, 1, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "I"
coman.ExecuteNonQuery()
Buscar()
Limpiar()

--COMBO--
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Codigo")
dt.Columns.Add("Descripcion")
Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
dr1.Item("Codigo") = "A"
dr1.Item("Descripcion") = "Activo"
dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
Dim dr2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
dr2.Item("Codigo") = "I"
dr2.Item("Descripcion") = "Inactivo"
dt.Rows.Add(dr2)
cmbEstado.DataSource = dt
cmbEstado.ValueMember = "Codigo"
cmbEstado.DisplayMember = "Descripcion"

--GRIDVIEW--
--1--
Dim grdFila As DataGridViewRow = grdClientes.CurrentRow
txtCedula.Text = grdFila.Cells(0).Value
--2--
If DataGridProductos.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    Dim FLstArticulos As New FLstArticulos
    FLstArticulos.ShowDialog()
    DataGridProductos.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = FLstArticulos.PrIdArticulo
End If

--GRIDVIEW.CELLENDEDIT--
If DataGridProductos.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
    Dim precio As New Double
    Dim cantidad As New Double
    precio = CDbl(grdRow.Cells(2).Value)
    cantidad = CDbl(grdRow.Cells(3).Value)
    DataGridProductos.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = PLTotalFilaItem(cantidad, precio)
    PLCargaTotales()
End If

Sub PLCargaTotales()
    Dim subTotal As Double
    Dim iva As Double
    For Each grd As DataGridViewRow In DataGridProductos.Rows
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(grd.Cells(4).Value) Then
            subTotal = subTotal + CDbl(grd.Cells(4).Value)
        End If
    Next grd
    txtSubtotal.Text = subTotal.ToString
    iva = Decimal.Round(subTotal * 0.12)
    txtIva.Text = iva.ToString
    txtTotalPagar.Text = (subTotal + iva).ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide some explaination for the code only answer it doen't tend to be very helpful without any description.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this method and it works properly.

```
                            Dim dt As New DataTable
                            Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn("MOBILENUMBER")
                            dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
                            dc.MaxLength = 15
                            dt.Columns.Add(dc)
                            For n As Integer = 0 To dgvMobiles.Rows.Count - 2
                                dtr = dt.NewRow()
                                dtr.Item("MOBILENUMBER") = dgvMobiles.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value
                                dt.Rows.Add(dtr)
                            Next
```

Where **dgbMobiles** is the datagridview which i can enter my contacts mobile numbers.

I hope that is usu