# How to cast Databound Gridview to Datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am trying to add row to my **datagridview** which is **databound**

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Dim Index As Integer
    'Index = DataTable1DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim dt As DataTable = DataTable1DataGridView.DataSource
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

End Sub
```

**Error:** Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: Look at type cast functions.  ie CType(DataTable1DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20209348/13393566) answer you question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong. You have a `BindingSource` for a reason so use it. You don't need to access the `DataTable` at all. Just use the `BindingSource`, which you should be able to refer to directly, so you don't need the grid either.

```vb
Dim rowView = DirectCast(DataTable1BindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)

rowView("SomeColumn") = someValue
DataTable1BindingSource.EndEdit()
```

When you bind a `DataTable`, the data actually comes from the `DefaultView` property, which is a `DataView`. That's why each item is a `DataRowView` rather than a `DataRow`. You can treat a `DataRowView` just like you do a `DataRow` in many situations, including this one. If you have a typed `DataSet` though, you might prefer to use a typed `DataRow`. In that case, get the `DataRow` from the `Row` property of the `DataRowView` and cast it as the appropriate type:

```vb
Dim rowView = DirectCast(DataTable1BindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)
Dim row = DirectCast(rowView.Row, DataTable1DataRow)

rowView.SomeColumn = someValue
DataTable1BindingSource.EndEdit()
```

Answer (score 2):

here

```
Dim dt As DataTable = DataTable1DataGridView.DataSource
```

you have `DataSource` is object and it points to `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource`, not `DataTable`.

you need to get `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`

```
dim ds as DataSet = 
    DirectCast(DirectCast(DataTable1DataGridView.DataSource, BindingSource).DataSource, DataSet)
```

Comment: Previous error is gone, and now-> Unable to cast object of type 'GridViewDemo.DataSet1' to type 'System.Data.DataTable

Comment: @BlackCat, so, your datasource in the binding source is not a datatable butr dataset. I updated the answer

Comment: New error: NewRow is not a member of Dataset, Its obvious. But, all I wanted to add a row by the code :)

Comment: @BlackCat your table is in DataSet table collection - `DataSet.Tables[0].NewRow`. Why don't you look in documentation, the hierarchy  graph??